# ioctrl using SCSI pass through

Tags: c++, c, linux, scsi

Using Windows I can easily communicate with my USB device using the following simplified code:

```
DWORD dwJunk;    // discard results from DeviceIOControl()
int   iReply;
char  cBuffer[100];
// cBuffer is initialized here.
HANDLE hDevice; // handle to the drive to be examined 
CString sDrive = _T(\\\\.\\H:); // drive H: for this test
hDevice = CreateFile(sDrive,            // drive to open
   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,        // read and write access to the drive
   FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,  // share mode           
   NULL,                                // default security attributes
   OPEN_EXISTING,                       // disposition
   0,                                   // file attributes
   NULL);                               // do not copy file attributes

iReply = DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT, &cBuffer, sizeof(cBuffer), &cBuffer, sizeof(cBuffer), &dwJunk, (LPOVERLAPPED)NULL);
```

I'm trying to do the same in linux but have not been able to figure out the ioctrl() parameters, or better put the structure. A code snippet would be vey much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the code I modified using your link didn't return any results. Here's the stripped code I used. ioctl() returned without errors:

```
#define DEF_TIMEOUT 5000 // 5 seconds
char cDiskName[] = "/dev/sg3";
int fd = open(cDiskName, O_RDWR);
if (fd < 0)
{
  printf("Open error: %s, errno=%d (%s)\n", cDiskName, errno, strerror(errno));
  return 1;
}

unsigned char turCmbBlk[] = {0x00, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
struct sg_io_hdr io_hdr;

unsigned char cIOBuffer[100];

// buffer initialization code omitted

memset(&io_hdr, 0, sizeof(struct sg_io_hdr));
io_hdr.interface_id = 'S';
io_hdr.cmd_len = sizeof(turCmbBlk);
io_hdr.mx_sb_len = sizeof(cIOBuffer);
io_hdr.dxfer_direction = SG_DXFER_NONE;
io_hdr.cmdp = turCmbBlk;
io_hdr.sbp = cIOBuffer;
io_hdr.timeout = DEF_TIMEOUT;
if (ioctl(fd, SG_IO, &io_hdr) < 0)
{
  printf("ioctl error: errno=%d (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}

// Code returned here without any errors but cIOBuffer remains unchanged.
```

Maybe the call needs a different request code?

Comment: Please replace `io_hdr.dxfer_direction = SG_DXFER_NONE` (= *no data transfer*) with `io_hdr.dxfer_direction = SG_DXFER_TO_FROM_DEV` (= *transfer in both directions*).

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. I tried using SG_DXFER_TO_FROM_DEV in place of SG_DXFER_NONE, but my buffer is still returned unchanged.

Comment: Please take a look at my changes (*edit* of my answer). my changes are marked with `// -` comments. Changes: a.) dynamic memory, b.) flags set, c.) usage of dxferp.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the dxferp parameter, but this is what I did: After the definition of replyBuffer I added     memcpy(replyBuffer, cIOBuffer, BUFF_SIZE); and then modified your dxferp to dxferp = replyBuffer. Is this what you meant? The call returns without error but both cIOBuffer and the new replyBuffer are still unchanged (both identical).

Comment: Yes, you are right, `dxferp = replyBuffer`; write error. (btw. ive added two more links, i hope they can help you a bit).

Comment: Well, thanks for trying. At least I have a starting point, but I'll most probably have to make another posting in the near future. I don't understand why it's so simple in Windows but so difficult in linux. But I'll read up a bit first.

Comment: Hey, I used SG_DXFER_TO_FROM_DEV in your second piece of code and now the cIOBuffer becomes changed! Not what it should be, but something's happening....

Comment: I see! now we have to figure out where to set the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some more documentation:

- [Notes on Linux's SG driver version 2.1.36](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/FAQ/OS/Linux/SCSI-Generic-FAQ.html)
- *SCSI-Programming*, [page 8](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO-8.html) *(`handle_SCSI_cmd` function)*, [page 9](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO-9.html), [page 11](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO-11.html) *(example)* and some more
- [Generic SCSI Target Subsystem for Linux](http://scst.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

See here:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int ioctl(int d, int request, ...);
```

**Parameters:**

1. **Filedescriptor** (must be open!)
2. **Request code** number (depends on device)
3. **Untyped pointer** to memory (going to / coming from driver)

**Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/usbdevice_fs.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *filename;
    int fd;

    filename = argv[1];

    fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY);
    ioctl(fd, USBDEVFS_RESET, 0);

    close(fd);

    return;
}
```

**Documentation:**

- [ioctl(2) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl)
- [IOCTL(2)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ioctl&sektion=2)
- [Generic I/O Control operations (GNU libc)](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/IOCTLs.html)
- [The ioctl() Requests](http://tali.admingilde.org/linux-docbook/usb/ch07s06.html)
- [usb.c](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/usb.c) *(Example that might help you)*
- [Linux / Unix Command: ioctl](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_ioctl.htm)
- [How to Reset USB Device in Linux](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-reset-usb-device-in-linux/) *(Example)*
- [An example Program with IOCTL](http://embedded.seattle.intel-research.net/wiki/index.php?title=An_example_Program_with_IOCTL)

---

**Edit**

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 100 // - Buffersize

#define DEF_TIMEOUT 5000 // 5 seconds
char cDiskName[] = "/dev/sg3";
int fd = open(cDiskName, O_RDWR);
if (fd < 0)
{
  printf("Open error: %s, errno=%d (%s)\n", cDiskName, errno, strerror(errno));
  return 1;
}

unsigned char turCmbBlk[] = {0x00, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
struct sg_io_hdr *p = (struct sg_io_hdr *) malloc(sizeof(struct sg_io_hdr)); // - dynamic memory allocation - free() required somewhere

unsigned char cIOBuffer[BUFF_SIZE];
unsigned char replyBuffer[BUFF_SIZE]; // - dxfer buffer

// buffer initialization code omitted

memset(p, 0, sizeof(struct sg_io_hdr));
p->interface_id = 'S';
p->cmd_len = sizeof(turCmbBlk);
p->mx_sb_len = BUFF_SIZE;
p->dxfer_direction = SG_DXFER_NONE;
p->cmdp = turCmbBlk;
p->sbp = cIOBuffer;
p->timeout = DEF_TIMEOUT;
p->flags = SG_FLAG_DIRECT_IO; // - Does this help?
p->dxferp = replyBuffer; // - Set dxferp buffer - (A)
p->dxfer_len = BUFF_SIZE; // - buffersize

if (ioctl(fd, SG_IO, p) < 0)
{
  printf("ioctl error: errno=%d (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}

// Code returned here without any errors but cIOBuffer remains unchanged.
```

*Note (A):* Please try setting your input / output buffer you work on here.

**Documentation:**

- [SCSI Generic HOWTO, SG_IO_HDR_T](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/SCSI-Generic-HOWTO.html#SG_IO_HDR_T)
- [Tour the Linux generic SCSI driver](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-scsi-api/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post the links. Your parameters would be exactly what I'm looking for, but I believe the magic word is the request code for the Windows "IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT" equivalent. I've already been searching on and off for well over 2 weeks but haven't found any code that works in Linux. In Windows the code works with standard drivers so I don't believe the request code depends on the device. All I want to do is send the buffer to the USB device. The USB device will then update the buffer accordingly.

Comment: Is `SG_IO` what you need? *"The SG_IO ioctl permits user applications to send SCSI commands to a device."* [see here](http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sg_io.html)

Comment: I've just looked up SG_IO and it sounds prommising except it needs a correctly filled in sg_io_hdr_t - and this looks most complicated, especially in that it needs a SCSI command, which I don't have. All I want to do is transparently send a 100 byte buffer to the USB device. In Windows it's so easy, I just supply the buffer and the size of the buffer. Surely something like this must exist in linux? [EDIT] I've just looked again at your last link and it may be what I want. I'll have to wait until tomorrow to try it out. I'll reply tomorrow.

Comment: Did you [SCSI Generic HowTo](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-Generic-HOWTO/index.html), especially [write()-function](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-Generic-HOWTO/write.html)?

Comment: I have just also tried with write and read. Both functions appear to work but my buffer remains unchanged